# Чем отличаются понятия iterable и sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, терминология, итераторы

Не могу понять, чем отличаются понятия "итерируемый" и "последовательность" в Python. Поясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Итерируемый объект ([iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)) позволяет последовательно просмотреть свои элементы. Но возможности обратиться к произвольному элементу может не быть.

Последовательность ([sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence)) - это итерируемый объект, к элементам которого можно обратиться по целочисленному индексу, а также можно узнать общее количество элементов (длину последовательности).

Примеры:

- `list`, `tuple`, `str` - это последовательности
- функции-генераторы, файловые объекты, объекты `zip`, `iter`, `map` и т.д. - итерируемые объекты (более конкретно - итераторы)
- `dict` - является итерируемым объектом, но не является последовательностью (обращение к значениям не по целочисленному индексу, а по ключу, которым может быть любой [хешируемый](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable)  объект), если более конкретно - относится к [mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping) объектам.

Дополнительно о разнице итерируемого объекта (iterable) и итератора ([iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)):

- `Iterator` как и `Iterable` позволяет последовательно просмотреть свои элементы, но (обычно) только один раз (так называемое, исчерпание итератора, iterator exhausting). Так, например, ведут себя объекты, возвращаемые функциями `map`, `zip`, генераторы (функции, возвращающие значения через `yield`), выражения-генераторы ([generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), аналог list comprehension, но с круглыми скобками вместо квадратных, или вообще без дополнительных скобок, если передаются напрямую в какую-то функцию).
- С формальной точки зрения `Iterator` должен реализовывать методы `__iter__` и `__next__`, а чтобы объект был `Iterable`, ему достаточно реализовать метод `__iter__`. См. [`collections.abc.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable), [`collections.abc.Iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterator). Таким образом, ***формально*** любой итератор является итерируемым объектом, т.к. реализует метод `__iter__`, но не любой итерируемый объект является итератором (не у каждого `Iterable` реализован метод `__next__`).

  С практической точки зрения: у итерируемых объектов (не итераторов) метод `__iter__` возвращает новый итератор (обычно - каждый раз новый, благодаря чему по итерируемому объекту можно итерироваться много раз), а у итератора `__iter__` возвращает сам объект (`self`).

  `Sequence` (см. [`collections.abc.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence)) объекты также реализуют метод `__iter__` (в числе прочих методов), поэтому являются `Iterable`, но как правило не являются итераторами.

Comment: Добавлю, что итерируемый объект может вообще не иметь конца. То есть он не содержит внутри себя сколько-то элементов, а каждый раз по запросу по определённому принципу генерит новый элемент.

Comment: Во втором пункте допущена ошибка:
функции-генераторы, файловые объекты, объекты zip, iter, map и т.д. - это итераторы, а не итерируемые объекты.

Comment: @ХачатурСаркисян итераторы являются итерируемыми объектами. Точно так же как и функции являются callable объектами.

Comment: С этими понятиями какая-то каша =))) Я могу ошибаться, но я понял для себя это так: итерируемый объект - объект, подверженный протоколу итерации. Итератор - объект, подготовленный к итерации, полученный из итерируемого объекта с помощью iter

Comment: @Demmiat я все в ответе расписал, никакой каши нет. На практике по итерируемому объект можно пройти несколько раз, потому что его метод `__iter__` каждый раз возвращает новый итератор. По итератору можно проитерироваться только один раз, его метод `__iter__` возвращает сам же этот итератор.